# Oxyplot annotation with brush

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, oxyplot

I wish to colour my `OxyPlot`'s `RectangleAnnotation` with something more pretty than just a plain colour, i.e. some type of `brush` (`GradientBrush` etc.). I am working in WPF.

This question ([PlotAreaBackground can be defined using gradient ?](https://github.com/oxyplot/oxyplot/issues/538)) on their GitHub site suggests that an annotation can be given a gradient, but I cannot find the suggested example.

Is there a way of applying a brush to a `RectangleAnnotation`? or any other way of creating coloured areas on a graph that are linked to the values on the axis?

Comment: Have you looked here? http://resources.oxyplot.org/examplebrowser/

Answer (score 2):

I think that this is the [suggested example](https://hg.codeplex.com/forks/lsowen/fixtextannotation/rev/690517617c41).

I've modified it to look like a rectangle annotation, because the example fills the entire background. Hope it helps.

**Efect:**

[image]

**Code:**

```
// create a gradient image of height n
int n = 256;
var imageData1 = new OxyColor[n, 1];
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    imageData1[i, 0] = OxyColor.Interpolate(OxyColors.Red, OxyColors.Blue, i / (n - 1.0));
}

PngBitmapEncoder encoder = new PngBitmapEncoder();
PngEncoder encode = new PngEncoder(new PngEncoderOptions());
var image1 = new OxyImage(encode.Encode(imageData1));

ImageAnnotation anotation = new ImageAnnotation
{
    ImageSource = image1,
    Interpolate = true,
    Layer = AnnotationLayer.BelowAxes,
    X = new PlotLength(0.5, PlotLengthUnit.RelativeToPlotArea),
    Y = new PlotLength(0.5, PlotLengthUnit.RelativeToPlotArea),
    Width = new PlotLength(0.1, PlotLengthUnit.RelativeToPlotArea),
    Height = new PlotLength(0.5, PlotLengthUnit.RelativeToPlotArea),
    HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left,
    VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top
};
plotModel.Annotations.Add(anotation);
```